# Retrieve all Value from Multiple Parameter

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

**Goal**

Send and retrieve the value of a picture and variable `testtest` from frontend to backend.

**Problem**

When I get the `int testtest` in the backend, it shows value `0` but I want to have `10` instead.

What part am I missing?

**Info**

- Angular and c.net core is separated and they are not in the same solution.
  VS code is used for Angular and VS 2017 for .net core.
- The frontend code is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awfxes
  The source code is "https://w3path.com/new-angular-8-file-upload-or-image-upload/"
- Backend code c# core is below

Thank you!

---

Code:

```c#
[HttpPost("addFile")]
public async Task AddFile(IFormFile files, int testtest)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
    var filePath = Path.Combine("C:\\test", fileName);

    using (var fileSteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await files.CopyToAsync(fileSteam);
    }         
}
```

Comment: What is the actual post that you are sending / how are you sending it?

Comment: The variable `testtest` is in the httpOptions part of the argument in your angular httpClient (post)... you might want to move it to eg. the path/route or in http header and on the c# side, [FromRoute] or reading from the http header

Comment: Please post the relevant front end code as well, not a link to it.

Comment: you need to add your `testtest` to form like this `formData.append('testtest', 10);`

Comment: Oleg, it works!

Comment: I guess I could compile answer for someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `testtest` to form like this :

```
 const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', this.fileData);
    formData.append('testtest', 10);
    this.fileUploadProgress = '0%';

    this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/values/addfile', formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'   
    })
```